# Backup MySQL with LVM, questions about the MySQL Session

Tags: mysql, backup, lvm, session

I want backup my mysql database with lvm. I will do the backup with cronjob. Here the pseudocode

1. Open mysql session
2. Run SQL `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`
3. Do backup `lvcreate -l100%FREE -s -n mysql-backup /dev/vg00/lv_var`
4. Run SQL `UNLOCK TABLES`
5. done

Between step 2 until 4, **mysql session must keep opened**.

So now I have solved this in my script:

```
mysql -u root -prootpwd -e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK";
lvcreate -l100%FREE -s -n mysql-backup /dev/vg00/lv_var
mysql -u root -prootpwd -e "UNLOCK TABLES";
```

but **how to keep the mysql session open in my script?**

Normally, I should open mysql session to run `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` but not terminating the this mysql session. In another shell I should do the `lvcreate` command, after that I must unlock the tables in the first shell.

The other part with second mysql instance and mysqldump working without problems.

How I can do that?

Comment: don't reinvent a wheel. Use mylvmbackup. This problem was solved 10 years ago

Comment: hello, mylvmbackup backup backups the whole (in my case) /var (including /var/www) directory. so i only need a mysql-backup...
or can i setup lvmbackup to backup ONLY the /var/lib/mysql folder? thanks

Comment: I usually allocate a partition for MySQL only. This is right thing to do in general and make mylvmbackup happy too.